# Wallet Management with paypal

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

**I want to make an app in which I have a wallet management functionality.**

1- Users can deposit money to PayPal Merchant account

2- Users can withdraw money from PayPal Merchant account

What I have to do is I don't want my users to leave my website and give them the ability to deposit and withdraw their money from my platform.

What are the PayPal APIs should I use for this purpose?

I don't want to use Braintree SDK as it is not reflecting credit card transactions on PayPal business account which I want for reconciliation.

For depositing money I found PayPal Payment Pro as the best solution but I don't know how to implement this as it does not have any developer guide given on PayPal